# I removed the Unity ads service from my game but google play still say my app contains ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads

I have completely removed Unity's ads service from my game and deleted all the code relevant to it. The game shows no ads and it doesnt even have a reference to UnityEngine.Advertisment. This is my manifest where I also see nothing connected to ads yet on google play it still say that the app contains ads.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.LeadersPlay.LeadStreet" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionName="1.26" android:versionCode="45" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:isGame="true">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.LeadersPlay.LeadStreet.UnityPlayerActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="21447188-7121-4c3e-8f0e-6602ae1caa74" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out there is a checkbox in the google dev console that specifies wheter the app has ads or not. It was under the pricing section.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. By google dev console do you mean the website where you upload your build to?